# Add current date to SQL query followed by number

Tags: sql, sql-server, date

I have a SQL query which returns transactions for the previous day, so every morning the query runs and exports all transactions into a file for the previous day. I have a column called `Id` and in here at the moment its just `0`, what I would like to do is insert here the date and a number so it forms something like a `unique Id` for each transaction in the file.. So for example, the first transaction Id will be `27071500001` and the last transaction Id will be `27071511234`. The date would need to be the previous day and not the current one How could I do this?

Here is where I select the Id..

```
SELECT  Id,
            PaidAt    = CASE
                            WHEN NOT(l_pay.ShortName IS NULL) THEN    l_pay.ShortName
                            ELSE ''
                        END,
            DateIn    = CASE
                            WHEN NOT(tr.EntryDate IS NULL) THEN CONVERT(VARCHAR, tr.EntryDate, 112)
                            ELSE ''
                        END,                                  
            TimeIn    = CASE
                            WHEN NOT(tr.EntryTime IS NULL) THEN  REPLACE(tr.EntryTime, ':', '')
                            ELSE ''
                        END,
            DateOut   = CASE
                            WHEN NOT(tr.ExitDate IS NULL) THEN CONVERT(VARCHAR, tr.ExitDate, 112)
                            ELSE ''
                        END,                        
            TimeOut   = CASE
                            WHEN NOT(tr.ExitTime IS NULL) THEN REPLACE(tr.ExitTime, ':', '')
                            ELSE ''
                        END,
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: We can't track record created time. So you need to maintain one seperate column for that,

Comment: Added `sql-server` tag based on the usage of `convert()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [CONVERT](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&ved=0CCMQFjABahUKEwj24uTrm_vGAhWBCI4KHWfoBkA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fen-us%2Flibrary%2Fms187928.aspx&ei=VBe2VfboDoGRuATn0JuABA&usg=AFQjCNHqftsfRyjybURhYO35GuG_mwrNZg&bvm=bv.98717601,d.c2E&cad=rja) function to get different date formats like

```
1) CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), GETDATE()-1, 112) /* Returns date like 20150726 */
2) REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), GETDATE()-1, 104),'.','') /* Returns date like 26072015 */
3) REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), GETDATE()-1, 104),'.','') + 
   REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), GETDATE()-1, 108),':','')
/* Returns date and time like 26072015170032*/
```

**UPDATE**

For that you have to use [ROW_NUMBER()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx) function like below :

```
SELECT REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), GETDATE()-1, 104),'.','') + 
CAST(ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY Id) AS VARCHAR(20)) FROM TableName
```

To add leading zeros in number you need to pad string like below :

```
SELECT REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), GETDATE()-1, 104),'.','') + 
RIGHT('00000'+ CAST(ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY Id) AS VARCHAR(20)),5) FROM TableName
```

Comment: great, thank you for the date format.. This works as expected.. I don't want to add the time so i have used the 104 format.. If I wanted to add a number onto this, is that possible? So the returned result would be 26072015(5 digit number) the 5 digit number is really a count for number of rows.. so row 1 would have Id 2607201500001.. and so on..

Comment: Thank you so much for the help.. This has worked.. Thankyou.. I just have one last question... If I wanted to add leading zero's to the row number how would I add this? the row number should always be 5 digits plus date as the header..So if row number 1 should be returned at 00001

Comment: Check updated answer with pad string of leading zeros.